# How to implement an application/website wide form in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: view, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form2

In my ZF2 aplication I have multiple modules and one of them is "Search". It provides a search form, the search logic and a list of courses found in the database:

**Form class**

```
namespace Search\Form;

...

class CourseSearchForm extends Form {

    private $cities;

    public function __construct(array $cities) {
        parent::__construct('courseSearch');
        $this->setCities($cities);
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'keyword',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'city',
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Stadt',
                'value_options' => $this->cities
            ),
        ));
        // ...
    }

    public function setCities(array $cities) {
        $this->cities = $cities;
    }

}
```

**Controller class**

```
namespace Search\Controller;

...

class SearchController extends AbstractActionController {

    protected $courseTable;

    public function searchAction() {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('search-courses');
    }

    public function searchCoursesAction() {
        $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Search\Form\CourseSearchForm');
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $courseSearchInput = new CourseSearchInput();
            $form->setInputFilter($courseSearchInput->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $courseSearchInput->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                $courses = $this->getCourseTable()->findAllByCriteria($courseSearchInput);
            } else {
                $courses = null;
            }
        } else {
            $courses = null;
        }
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form,
            'courses' => $courses,
            'cities' => $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Cache\Model\CityStorage')->getCities(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Gets a CourseTable object.
     * @return Search\Model\CourseTable
     */
    function getCourseTable() {
        if (!$this->courseTable) {
            $serviceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->courseTable = $serviceLocator->get('Search\Model\CourseTable');
        }
        return $this->courseTable;
    }

}
```

**List view in `/module/Search/view/search/search/search-courses.phtml`**

```
...
<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('search-courses'));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('keyword'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('city'));
// ...
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
?>
<?php
if ($courses instanceof Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSetInterface) {
    echo $this->render('search/search/list-courses.phtml', array(
        'courses' => $courses
    ));
}
?>
```

Now the search form should be displayed on every page of the website. How can I implement such global form view? Is there a "standard" way / best practice to do this?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd simply create a `ViewHelper`. You'd inject the Form into the ViewHelper and then you render the View and return it. The ViewHelper itself could look very similar to what ZfcUser offers within [`ZfcUser\View\Helper\ZfcUserLoginWidget`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/View/Helper/ZfcUserLoginWidget.php)

Comment: @automatix It's not me who did it, it's the community. Your code is nothing more to what i have linked as an example ViewHelper and basically is only another answer ;) Simply do such things as an answer, maybe it will be considered better than mine and yours will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

some way to display it:

### 1. Create your own view helper

to inspire you,

- http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/zend-framework-2-create-your-custom-view-helper/
- http://robertbasic.com/blog/working-with-custom-view-helpers-in-zend-framework-2

### 2. Use the plugin forward

```
    // menu user
    $menu = $this->forward()->dispatch('edit_controller', array(
        'action'    => 'menu',
        'item' => 'languages',
        'id' => $id,
    ));
    $viewmodel->addChild($menu, 'menu');
```

I prefer the use of the [plugin forward](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-forward-plugin)

Comment: A ViewHelper has much less overhead than the `forward()` would.

Comment: Other ways I forgot to write are:
- Partial view <?php echo $this->partial("mypartial"); ?>
- and layout variables <?php echo $this->layout()->variables; ?>

Comment: A partial renders only a template, it doesn't know about the form - you can't manually instantiate a form on every request in every action. A Layout-Variable would be very much a wrong approach for the given use-case. forward() or ViewHelper are the options of choice and as mentioned above, the ViewHelper is the likelier one to go for due to less overhead